# data is duplicated when i come back to the same page again

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, lifecycle

I'm Using `ionViewWillEnter` and `ionViewWillLeave` as a life cycle hooks for my ionic project pages, but in some page, the data is being duplicated if I navigated to another page and back to it. it adds the new data fetched in `ionViewWillEnter` to the old data.

What I need to do is to set up `ionViewWillLeave` the right way to make sure that all of the old fetched data are gone.

here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '../services/language.service';
import { Dress, DressService } from '../services/dress.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-ads',
  templateUrl: './my-ads.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-ads.page.scss'],
})
export class MyAdsPage {
  allDress: Dress[];
  theSub: any;
  currentEmail = '';

  constructor(
    private currentLanguage: LanguageService,
    private dressService: DressService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.currentEmail = this.authService.userDetails().email;
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.theSub = this.dressService.getDressesForMyAds().subscribe(res => {
      this.allDress = res;
    });
    console.log('myAds started');
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.theSub.unsubscribe();
    console.log('myAds leaved');
  }

  getCurrentLanguage() {
    return this.currentLanguage.getCurrentLanguage();
  }

  changeToArabic() {
    this.currentLanguage.changeToArabic();
  }

  changeToEnglish() {
    this.currentLanguage.changeToEnglish();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `ionViewWillLeave` and change it with this:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.theSub.unsubscribe();
    console.log('myAds leaved');
    // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
    for (const member in this.allDress) { delete this.allDress[member]; }
  }
```

Deleting fetching data before leacing fixed it all.
`for (const member in this.allDress) { delete this.allDress[member]; }`